# Xcode error. Can't build iOS app with Mapbox API cloned from my Git rep

Tags: xcode, git, git-lfs, mapbox-ios

Unfortunately me and my small team don't have a lot of experience in iOS developing and we really need some help. I have created git rep with our project, also I use Git LFS for files from Mapbox API. But then I try to clone my project from rep and build the app I get this error ([Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fekK.png)). I have some ideas how to solve this problem, but I don't know which solution is better. [Link to my rep](https://github.com/Sidor247/Cycle-Trip), if needed.

Comment: Well the file that is claiming to be a framework binary file starts with the texts `version https://`-something so it's corrupt.  I've no idea how.  Why are you even tracking those pods in your git repo?

Comment: @trojanfoe I think, it's because the required file stored in lfs folder and on this path actually stored other file which was created by lfs(which starts with the texts). As I thought it is just a reference to required file or something like that and xcode will find right file's path automatically. Do you think that I should add pods in .gitignore? 
Just found out that I can do it. But  I don't understand how our team will work with project. Each guy needs to install pods independently, right?

Comment: Yes ignore the `pods` directory.  They are external deps that will update overtime and part of setting-up the development workspace will be initialising them.

Comment: @trojanfoe All works good, thank you!